Azure OpenAI Studio Playground: My assistant always returns undefined error when submitting an output to any functions
In Azure OpenAI Studio, I created a new assistant and added the sample "get_weather" function. In the playground, I chat with the assistant and ask about the weather. It answers with the function name and argument and it requires to submit an output. Whatever output I submit it says "Error undefined: undefined". I tried outputs like:

the weather is nice
output: the weather is nice
{output: the weather is nice}
{"output": "the weather is nice"}

It worked once (I don't recall for which version) but when I tried again with the exact same output then it failed again.

I would recommend you to go this Function Calling article in programmatic way for further visibility https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/how-to/function-calling

Try out the new Assistants tab in azure ai foundry. It has now a send function call result icon now. see below. The issue of the old playground is that chat window does not have a way to send function call result correctly from browser.

